# Behaviour of captures in capture-list [c++]

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm getting confused about the behaviour of `captures` in `capture-list`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

    auto m = [a, &b, &c]() mutable
    {
        std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';  // prints 122
        a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
    };

    a = 2; b = 2; c = 2;

    m();                              
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';     // prints 233
}
```

Output:

```
122
233
```

If lambda function is declared inside another one:

```
auto m1 = [a, &b, &c]() mutable
{
    auto m2 = [a, b, &c]() mutable
    {
        std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
        a = 4; b = 4; c = 4;
    };

    a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
    m2();
};
```

As far I understood,

- when a lambda function is defined, `by-copy` capture is initialized with its current value.
- `by-reference` capture is initialized when function is called.
- `by-copy` capture can't affect outside of its block.
- `by-reference` capture can change its original value.

Am I right? I've studied but I didn't get it clearly. Can anyone explain it?.

Comment: So what output do you expect?

Comment: sorry? I am trying to understand what is happening here. I didn't say that output is wrong or i expect anything else

Comment: I'd say the capture is "initialized" at the moment the lambda is declared. Otherwise it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, why?  I can see two outputs. One inside lambda function, another at the end of main block.

Comment: all of them? @juanchopanza

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes, all of them of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this lambda-expression

```
auto m = [a, &b, &c]() mutable
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';  // prints 122
    a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
};
```

the created object has its own copy of `a`. When the object was defined variable `a` had value 1.

For two other variables the object contains references.

You can imagine the lambda-expression the following way

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

class Unnamed
{
private:
    int a;
    int &b;
    int &c;
public:
    Unnamed( int a, int &b, int &c ) : a( a ), b( b ), c( c )
    {
    }

    void operator ()()
    {
        std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';  // prints 122
        a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
    }
} m( a, b, c );
```

So any changes of `a` after the lambda object definition do not influence on the corresponding data member of the object. However when variables `b` and `c` are being changed then the output of the corresponding operator function of the object will reflect these changes.

So after these statements

a = 2; b = 2; c = 2;

this call

```
 m();
```

will output the value of its own data member of the object that was initialized by the previous value of variable `a` and current values of `b` and `c` because it contains references to these variables.

So the output is

```
122
```

The second output

```
std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
```

reflects the current values of variables `a`, `b`, and `c` that are 2, 3, and 3 because inside the preceding call of the lambda variables `b` and `c` were changed. So you get

```
233
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Thank you sir for your explanation

Comment: If we nested this lambda, what will be the structure? class inside a class?

Comment: I modified my post for my last comment here

Comment: @AerofoilKite The type of a lambda expression is a unique unnamed non-union-class.. So inside another class it will look like an inner class.

Comment: @AerofoilKite In the second example the inner lambda has its own copy of a and b and the same reference to c.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda is essentially just a syntax sugar for functional object. Your code is equivalent to

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

    struct {
        int a;
        int& b;
        int& c;
        void operator()()
        {
            std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';  // prints 122
            a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
        }
    } m{a, b, c};

    a = 2; b = 2; c = 2;

    m();
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';     // prints 233
}
```

<sub>This is not strict explanation. Lambda can be converted to the function pointer if it does not capture. But in the particular example this is correct</sub>